# REACTjs Capture input box data on enter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to capture the value in a text box after the enter key is clicked.  I usually use onChange but that's not what I'm looking for.  In my code below, I am trying to use onKeydown but when I try to type in the textbox, nothing happens. Here's my code:

```
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      name:'',
      show:false
    }
    this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this)
  }
  
  handleKeyDown(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      this.setState({
        name:e.target.value
      })
    }
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <span>What is your name? </span>
        <input type="text" name="fullName" value={this.state.name} onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} /> 
        {this.state.show && <div>Hello {this.state.name}</div>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

Here's my [codepen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/pobZZgV)
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update the state when the input changes, and then do something with the value when the enter key is pressed.

```
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      show:false
    }
    this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this)
  }
  
  handleKeyDown(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      alert(this.state.name)
    }
  }
  
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <span>What is your name? </span>
        <input type="text" name="fullName" onChange={e=>this.setState({ name: e.target.value })} value={this.state.name} onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} /> 
        {this.state.show && <div>Hello {this.state.name}</div>}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
)
```

Comment: Thanks!! That made a lot of sense